# Bootstrap 4 - How to make a border that cover entire side of DIV

Tags: html, css

**Question:** Using Bootstrap 4. Im trying to make a leftside border on the SECOND DIV (col-md-1) that covers the WHOLE SIDE. Now it leaves padding on the upper and lower side. I'm willing to switch to just plain Flexbox for this example.

https://snag.gy/n92K8D.jpg

Code:

```
<div class="d-flex m-auto row no-padding opinion-list boxx-shadow bg-primary">
<div class="col-md-11">
  <ul class="list-inline m-auto">
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Today</a></li>
   <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Columnists</a></li>
   <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Editorial</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-1 bg-info no-padding" style="border-left: solid 1px silver;"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Any Tips?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen example?

Comment: Sure. Give me a second

Comment: Oh. I did solve it now. I forgot to remove padding in my own div. "opinion-list"  . I putted padding : 15px; when i should just put padding on left and right side. Sorry.

Comment: If you add something Awin I give you a Solution.It was probably you that kick-started my brain to fix it :)